# Google Now Stocks - customising

Tags: google-now

I was trying to add a stock - by trail and error - but I got it wrong. The newly added stock was not appearing in the 'Interested In' list so I was unable to delete it.
I have selected that I am no longer interested in stocks and don't know how to get them back.